# Definition of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: definition

The precise definition given in Dummit and Foote (sec 0.3, pg. 9) is the following:

> The definition of elements in residue class $x$ are those that are between $\bar0, \bar1, ..., \overline{x-1}$.
>
> Any integer congruent to any of these elements can be a representative of the element.

My answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128957/the-different-elements-of-mathbbz-157-mathbbz) was severely downvoted and got deleted:

> Hence, $\overline{768}$ CANNOT be an element of the class as many others have incorrectly pointed out - but $-768$ can be.
>
> Yes, $-768 \mod 157 \equiv \overline{17}$.

And why is this if I just quoted a definition from a respectable math book? It appears that Dummit and Foote (3e) is incorrect, then.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is really not clear. As the definition you mentioned : The definition of elements in residue class  are those that are between $\bar 0$, $\bar 1$,..., $\overline{x-1}$, that's definitely not correct. Element of residue class of $x$ (in $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$) are element of $\{x+Nk\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$ and not what you mentioned

Comment: Your answer was wrong (and not consistent with Dummit & Foote): $\overline{768}$ is a perfectly good element of the quotient, and coincides with $\overline{768 \pmod{157}}.$ Moreover, $-768$ is *not* an element of the quotient, because it's not a coset.

Comment: I'm not sure the negative reaction to this question is justified. There's a rantiness here, but also a perfectly good question, namely whether Dummit/Foote is incorrect or the OP is misunderstanding the situation. I agree the polemic should be removed, but I think we're being a bit too negative here.

Comment: @MorganRodgers That's a fair point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dummit and Foote is correct, and your answer was incorrect; the issue is that you seem to be misunderstanding what the quotient group is, and consequently what exactly Dummit and Foote are saying in the quoted passage.

*Below I write "$\overline{x}$" for the equivalence class of $x$ modulo $157$.*

The key point is that $\overline{768}$ is **literally the same thing as** $\overline{140}$, and is definitely an element of $\mathbb{Z}/157\mathbb{Z}$. The equality $\mathbb{Z}/157\mathbb{Z}=\{\overline{0},\overline{1},...,\overline{156}\}$ is correct; but it's *also* true that $\overline{178}\in\mathbb{Z}/157\mathbb{Z}$.

Meanwhile, a straight-up integer like $-768$ **isn't** an element of $\mathbb{Z}/157\mathbb{Z}$; rather, it's an element of *an element of* $\mathbb{Z}/157\mathbb{Z}$ (specifically, $-768\in\overline{17}$). That is:

- $\mathbb{Z}/157\mathbb{Z}$ is a set of sets of integers; as such, no integer is an element of $\mathbb{Z}/157\mathbb{Z}$.
- On the other hand, every integer is an element of a (unique) element of $\mathbb{Z}/157\mathbb{Z}$; namely, $x\in\overline{x}$.
- Moreover, every $x$ is in $\overline{y}$ for some (unique) $y\in\{0,1,2,..., 156\}$; in particular, combining this point with the previous one we have that if $x\not\in \{0,1,2,..., 156\}$ then "$\overline{x}$" is just a *different name for* some $\overline{y}$ with $y\in \{0,1,2,..., 156\}$.

Comment: After, when there are no confusion, we often use the short writing $x$ for $\bar x$.

Comment: @user649261 Quite right (and worth pointing out to the OP to forestall later confusion) - but that's notation you don't want to abuse too early!

Comment: Yes, I completely agree :)

Comment: There are $n$ distinct equivalence classes $\mod n$ - Dummit and Foote. $\overline{178}$ cannot be by definition an equivalence class

Comment: @JossieCalderon Not quite. "There are $n$ distinct equivalence classes mod $n$" That's correct. "$\overline{768}$ cannot be by definition an equivalence class" **That is incorrect**. "$\overline{768}$" is just **a different name for** $\overline{140}$, in the same way that $0.9999...$ is just a different name for $1$. There are indeed only $157$ distinct classes, and the thing we call $\overline{768}$ is one of them - namely, it's the same thing as $\overline{140}$. $a\not=b$ does **not** mean $\overline{a}\not=\overline{b}$, and this is in fact the key point about quotient groups. (continued)

Comment: It will help to shift from $157$ to something smaller, so you can think about this more concretely. Work mod $10$; looking at the definition of $\overline{a}$, do you see why $\overline{3}=\overline{13}$? (If not, what is something you think is in one set but not the other set?)

Comment: How can $\overline{768}$ exist by definition?

Comment: @JossieCalderon By definition, $\overline{a}$ - for **any** (integer) $a$ - is the set $\{b: b=a$ mod $n\}$ (where for us $n=157$ of course). For example (in our setting) we have $\overline{0}=\overline{157}=\overline{-157}=\overline{314}=...$ Now for $a\not\in\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$, the notation "$\overline{a}$" is in some sense redundant: we have $\overline{a}=\overline{s}$ (literally $=$: they are *the same sets of integers*) for some $s\in\{0,1,2,..., n-1\}$. But that doesn't make that notation *nonsensical* - it just means it's not going to be the *usual notation we use* to refer to that set.

Comment: @Jossie An analogy may help, the only positive rationals are $\,\overline{1/1},\ \overline{1/2},\ \overline{1/3},\overline{2/3},\, \overline{1/4},\overline{3/4}, \ldots$  but this does not imply that $\,\overline{2/4}\not\in\Bbb Q.\,$ It is in $\Bbb Q\,$ since $\, \overline{2/4} = \overline{1/2} = \{n/2n : n\neq 0\}$ all denote exactly the same equivalence class in $\Bbb Q.\ \ $

Comment: @JossieCalderon Do the explanations we've given help?

Comment: @Noah Yes. You're saying that there's $n$ sets, but infinite ways of saying it.

Comment: @JossieCalderon Glad we could help!